# How to to execute <script> tag coming in AJAX call, without making any change in client side JS

Tags: javascript, json, security-testing

```
[
    {
        "Book ID": "1",
        "Book Name": "UNIX **<script type='text/javascript'>alert('test')</script>**",
        "Category": "Computers",
        "Price": "113"
    }, 
    {
        "Book ID": "2",
        "Book Name": "Book two",
        "Category": "Programming",
        "Price": "562"
    }
]
```

This is the JSON I am sending via API I am sharing with multiple people. When I parse the JSON using JavaScript, `<script>` tag is not executed. What are the modification should I make in the JS injected into JSON so that `<script>` tag will be executed without doing any extra work at client side JS. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

If the techniques you are using to insert that code into the document do not trigger the JS, than changing what you are inserting won't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Find a flaw in the client page and exploit it, for example, if the client js get's the API answer and prints it in a `<label>` tag unsanitized, you could send something like `</label><script>alert(1)</script><label>` so your script would close the label, inject your script and open it again.

Or you could do a minimal modification in clientside and get the object from API as this:

```
{
    "Book ID": "1",
    "Book Name": "UNIX",
    "script": "alert('test')",
    "Category": "Computers",
    "Price": "113"
},
```

And then, in clientside run it with:

```
Function(obj.script)();
```